# Angular datatable select filter not working with 0 or false value

Tags: angularjs, datatable, angular-datatables

I'm using [Angular datatable](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/archives/#!/welcome) in **Server side processing** mode(Ajax) And use [Light Column Filter](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/archives/#!/withLightColumnFilter) plugin to filter data in each columns.

**HTML**

```
<table datatable dt-options="dtOptions" dt-columns="dtColumns"></table>
```

**Datatable config**

```
DTOptionsBuilder.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.fromSource()
    .withOption('processing', true)
    .withOption('serverSide', true)
    .withDataProp('data')
    .withPaginationType('full_numbers')
    .withOption('ajax', {
         url: '/products',
         type: 'GET',
         headers: {Authorization: 'Bearer ' + $auth.getToken()},
         error: function (xhr, error) {
            $log.error(error);
         },
         complete: function (data) {
            $log.log('Done');
         }
    })
    .withLightColumnFilter({
         '0': {type: 'text'},
         '1': {
            type: 'select',
            values: [
               { value: 1, label: 'Yes'},
               { value: 0, label: 'No'}
            ]
         }
    });
```

**create columns**

```
 $scope.dtColumns = [

    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('title').withTitle('title').renderWith(function(data) {
       return data;
    }),
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('for_sale').withTitle('for sale').renderWith(function(data){
       return data; // 0, 1 or true, false
   })
 ]
```

Filter with `type:'text'` is correct and work fine. But filter with `type:'select'` is incorrect! In the other words when I select **Yes** filter is work and data filtered, But when select **No** result is empty.

I test select value with `0,1` and `true,false`. In both ways, option with true or 1 value is correct but **option with 0 or false** value is incorrect.

In your opinion, where is the problem?

Comment: I cannot event get it to work half :( here is a plunkr to work with -> **http://plnkr.co/edit/GiLfIA5PwYFG1Muqkzko?p=preview**

Comment: @davidkonard why did you delete your answer?!

Comment: @davidkonard In plunkr use `type: 'select'`, not type: 'text',

Comment: I can always undelete if I figure out an answer :) But the current is not correct. Yes, the plunkr have some garbage, tried a lot of things, at the end the simplest possible, just hitted "fork" and posted the link here. It is a "serverside" with some data, could perhaps be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define the values as nunbers

```
values: [
  { value: 1, label: 'Yes'},
  { value: 0, label: 'No'}
]
```

But you return strings

```
return data; // 0, 1 or true, false
```

data will *always* be a string because the source is JSON. Try set both to strings and return `'0'` and `'1'` by force :

```
{ value: '1', label: 'Yes'},
{ value: '0', label: 'No'}
```

and

```
return data == '0' || data == 'false' ? '0' : '1'
```

Comment: Thanks @davidkonrad, But data that send by api is `boolean` (true,false) and I need this format in other places for checkboxes, what should I do?

Comment: @MortezaQorbanAlizade, what version / branch of LIght Column Filter are you using?

Comment: At the top of LIght Column Filter file is written: "angular-datatables - v0.6.3-dev"